# Express a sum of 2 determinants as a unique determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

**Given:**

$\left(\overline{a}\:,\:\overline{b}-2\overline{a}+\overline{c},\:\overline{b}\right)+\left(\overline{a}-2\overline{b},\:\overline{c},\:\overline{a}-\overline{c}\right)$

The answer must be $-3\left(\overline{a},\overline{b},\overline{c}\right)$

I think, we have to use these formulas:

[image]

and
$\left(\overline{a},\overline{b},\overline{b}\right)=0$

What do you think? Help me at least start.

Comment: I have modified you title in order it reflects the content of your question. Besides, I have suppressed the "calculus" tag : nothing here like differentiation, integration,... I have replaced it by "determinants".

Comment: @JeanMarie, ok, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the vectors are the columns of the matrix. We have that

\begin{align}\det(a,b-2a+c,b)&\underbrace{=}_{C_2-C_3\to C_2}det(a,-2a+c,b)\\&\underbrace{=}_{C_2+2C_1\to C_2}\det(a,c,b)\\&\underbrace{=}_{C_2\leftrightarrow C_3}-\det(a,b,c).\end{align} In a similar way

\begin{align}\det(a-2b,c,a-c)&\underbrace{=}_{C_3+C_2\to C_3}\det(a-2b,c,a)\\& \underbrace{=}_{C_1-C_3\to C_1}\det(-2b,c,a)\\&=-2\det(b,c,a)\\&\underbrace{=}_{C_2\leftrightarrow C_3}2\det(a,c,b)\\&\underbrace{=}_{C_1\leftrightarrow C_2}-2\det(a,b,c).\end{align}

Add both result and you are done.

Comment: What is the "det" ? Determinant?

Comment: Yes it is very necessary to use notation "det", in order to desambiguify notation $(a,b,c)$, which means a triple of vectors, not a determinant.

Comment: I still do not understand how we will get the answer.

Comment: I have editted the answer to clarify all steps.

Comment: So the answer should be different :(
There should be -3

Comment: It is $-3.$ You must add both results: $-1+(-2)=-3.$

Comment: Oh, sorry) I understood. Thank you for a lot!!!